# Converting from Tensorflow 1.13 to Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to get familiar with the new Tensorflow 2.0 by converting some code from 1.13 to 2.0. I'm a beginner with Tensorflow in general, but I thought continuing to learn 2.0 instead of 1.13 might be the better choice.

I already tried the conversion script but feel like it mainly only adds `tf.compat.v1` to the relevant parts.
The code is part of an A2C implementation and the Actor is supposed to work with a normal distribution. I'm not really sure how to  implement this part in Tensorflow 2.0, especially how to get mu and sigma as in the original code.

Here's the original code:

```py
def build_actor_net(self, scope, trainable):
        with tf.variable_scope(scope):
            dl1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=self.s, num_outputs=200,
                                                    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                                    trainable = trainable,
                                                    scope='dl1')

            mu = 2 * tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=dl1, num_outputs=self.num_action,
                                                    activation_fn=tf.nn.tanh,
                                                    trainable = trainable,
                                                   scope='mu')
            sigma = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=dl1, num_outputs=self.num_action,
                                                       activation_fn=tf.nn.softplus,
                                                       trainable=trainable,
                                                       scope='sigma')
            norm_dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma)


            return norm_dist
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
class Actor(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, act_dim):
        self.act_dim = act_dim

        super().__init__('mlp_policy')
        self.actor = keras.Sequential()

        self.actor.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))

        # Mu
        self.actor.add(2 * keras.layers.Dense(units=self.act_dim, activation='tanh'))

        # Sigma
        self.actor.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=self.act_dim, activation='softplus'))

        # PDB
        self.actor.pd = tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=self.mu, scale=self.sigma)
```

Obviously, `self.actor.add(2 * keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='tanh'))` won't work because of the multiplication. How do I correctly convert the code to version 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the `tf.keras.Model` class is to define your layers in `__init__` and you should implement the model's forward pass in `call`.

In your case:

```
class Actor(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, act_dim):
        super().__init__('mlp_policy')

        # Dl1
        self.dl1 = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')

        # Mu
        self.mu = keras.layers.Dense(units=act_dim, activation='tanh')

        # Sigma
        self.sigma = keras.layers.Dense(units=act_dim, activation='softplus')

    def call(self, inputs):
        dl1 = self.dl1(inputs)

        mu = 2 * self.mu(dl1)
        sigma = self.sigma(dl1)

        norm_dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma)
        return norm_dist
```